# The second-order relativistic correction is unreliable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, perturbation-theory

In his lectures on Quantum Theory, Frederic Schuller (lecture 8, at 2:03:00 and onwards) makes a remark about the unreliable nature of the second order perturbative correction of a relativistic system.

He says, in brief (and paraphrased) terms

> While the first-order correction of the perturbed eigenvalue only depends on the unperturbed eigenvalue and eigenvector of the same level, the second-order correction draws information from *all* the unperturbed eigenvalues and eigenvectors. As the deviation between the non-relativistic and relativistic energy levels become larger and larger at higher energies, the second-order correction may become useless.

While I certainly understand the picture he paints about the deviations becoming larger and larger as the relativistic limit eventually kicks in, I don't quite understand why the perturbation expansion somehow should be less accurate if the *non-approximated* Hamilonian has vastly different eigenvalues above a certain bound. This does not change anything of our unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_0$, which Schuller claims it does.

It may be that I have missed some crucial assumption, or maybe misinterpreted what is being said, but I would really appreciate any explanation lifting my confusion.

---

[Link to video](https://youtu.be/DWwOhIJQexY?t=7380)

Comment: As I see, he says it "may become useless" and not "less accurate". Something may be extremely accurate but still useless for the purpose of the experiment. Imagine an extremely accurate correction an of a $1 \, \mathrm{m}$ in the distance between Boston to New York for a car driver.

Comment: The wording is probably a bit ambiguous, I can see that. However, afterwards, he elaborates on the fact that in most cases, "... things conspire in such a way that the contributions from higher and higher energy levels contribute less and less so that this can be neglected." I regard this as more of a statement of the correction being *bad* albeit small, not useless in the sense you point out.